# Angular 6 HttpClient not converting response to Interface

Tags: angular6, angular-httpclient

I have an api endpoint that responds with a JSON Array as a string.

[image]

Correspondingly, I have an interface that matches the JSON response

[image]

I have a service that makes the request to get the array of users and logs the first record to the console.

[image]

**Expected Results**

I expect to get a UserDetails object back and should print all the contents of index 0 to the console.

**Actual Results**

In the console I just see the character '['. It seems that res variable is still being treated as a string, and not a UserDetails array.

I have been struggling for house to try and figure out what is causing this behavior

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem for anyone who is interested.

My server is returning the response in the body as a JSON string (this is a requirement from AWS API Gateway). The following has to be done to get the data to correctly parse.

[image]